# Need SQL aid for query with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, sas

I'm a beginner in sql and need some help using the left join (or alternate) function inthe following:

I have 2 tables:

1) Client

2) Server

Client has 2 columns (**country** and **clientname**) which is not present in Server. I want to join / copy these two columns into the Server table using the unique identifier column '**ClientID**' present in both tables to match and join. How would I go about doing this and does anything recommend an easier way? I currently don't have physical access to a DB so I can't really test out any queries, so any help is appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: This question is confusing. If you are going to be developing SQL, you really need a database. It's not at all clear why you don't have access to a database, since the MySQL community edition database is freely available.

Comment: Not sure I'm following your request.  Are you trying to join the two tables to produce a result or trying to copy data from one table into another table?  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.  BTW -- you always have access to databases -- consider sqlfiddle.com ...

Comment: I am away from the db with results but I just want to join the two columns from Client to Server. sorry for the vague explanation, i'm really quite bad at sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT s.*, c.country, c.clientname
  FROM server s LEFT JOIN client c 
    ON s.clientid = c.clientid
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a95b5/1)** demo.

For better understanding of `JOIN`s see [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: code works nicely but 1 question; does the ON statement mean WHERE s.clientid = c.clientid? So just making sure again, this code joins the country and clientname columns in "client" with server (i.e. these 2 cols are now in server as well) whilst matching clientid in server with clientid in client? thank again!

Comment: @user72757 Exactly. Note that you asked for `LEFT JOIN`. That means that even if a `clientid` is not specified (is null) for a particular server record that server record won't be filtered out from the resultset (as server4 in my sqlfiddle example). If `clientid` column in `server` table has a `NOT NULL` and foreign key constraints you may use `INNER JOIN` which might be faster.